# Keep Footnote Number with Chapter Title

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

I need to have a footnote attached to a word which forms a chapter heading; unfortunately, the footnote number appears lines below the word that needs to be explained.The footnote should be a superscript.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=9cm:16cm,DIV=15,fontsize=9pt,twocolumn,]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Apay}\footnote{``I arise'' in Guaran\'{i}.
}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do the same here using footnotemark/footnotetext (instead of footnote) and prefixing footnotemark with \protect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass[paper=9cm:16cm,DIV=15,fontsize=9pt,twocolumn,]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\chapter[Apay]{Apay\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{``I arise'' in Guaran\'{i}.}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]